# RESTKit: Overwriting objects where the objectID is the same, but other attributes have changed.

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

When I GET the server, I check the attribute "objectID" on each object, and if the objectID is already in the local store, I don't store the object.

Question:  What's the approach if the "objectID" exists, but its other attributes have changed and thus the entire object should be replaced with the new object?  There is an other attribute called "lastModified" that will change.  Do I compare against both "objectID" and "lastModified"?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, yes, compare the id and then check the modified date. Try not to replace the object though, instead, pass the new object to the existing object and have it update itself (then throw away the new object).

Note that if you were using Core Data then RestKit could handle this for you using unique identifier (so it can find the existing objects and update them during the mapping process).

Comment: I'm using the unique identifier. I thought that by using the unique identifier , it only looks for the objectId. Does it also check every attribute ?

Comment: No, only the unique identifier to find a match, and then each attribute is compared to decide if an update is required.

Comment: And that's RESTKits functionality be default?  The only thing I have to specify is a unique identifier?

Comment: When using Core Data, yes. You may also want to look at using KVC validation / not returning things that aren't updated from the server

Comment: I send lastrequest date to the server and the server only returns objects that's been modified after the lastrequest date. Is there a better way to do this with RESTKit  I should read up on?

Comment: No, that is the best option (the server doing it).